# Why is networking so slow in this Fig/Docker container?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, networking, docker, fig

I'm using [Fig](https://github.com/orchardup/fig) and Docker to containerise a sample Rails app. Currently, it works fine, the database and server start up. When I have an active Internet connection it all works perfectly. However when I don't have an Internet connection it takes **a long time to connect (20 seconds from the browser requesting the localhost page)** to the Rails/WEBrick server.

I've looked into the logs and nothing is out of the ordinary. It just takes a long time for the container to receive the initial connection and furthermore a long time to transmit the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I tested it, and it was because of DNS resolution. When you "disable" typical Google DNS and instead use localhost, the latency goes away. This is probably because without doing this Docker assumes that 127.0.0.1 is some address that needs to be looked up via a NS, and spends a lot of time waiting for a response (presumably because it sent it via UDP, it waits longer because of lost/dropped packets). This is also why the request wasn't recorded immediately, as DNS is at a lower-level on the net stack.

Comment: Can you tell me please what you mean by "disable" it? I tried just to remove the Google DNS entries (left with none, so using the default) but I'm still getting these huge delays... Can you tell me how to proper disable it? Thanks.

Comment: When you are connected to the network, this obviously doesn't apply. When you are not connected, you should add `dns: localhost` under the Fig service you are using (web for me).